# pathsplitting in Android with regular expressions

Tags: java, android, regex

I followed Ajb's recomendation here [Splitting String using RegEx in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912045/splitting-string-using-regex-in-android) and did it like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("JavaDoc")

public class DBUtility extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "Angler.sqlite3";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1; //minimal 1, 0 nicht zulÃ¤ssig.

    private String DB_PATH_COMPLETE;
    private String DB_PATH;
    private String DB_PATH_DISPLAY;
    private SQLiteDatabase SQL_DB;
    private Context myContext;
    private String displayText;
    private BufferedReader Rdr;
    private char[] SQLstringAr;
    private String SQLstatementFile;
    private Cursor cur;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DBUtility(Context context) {
        // Kann nicht private werden
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION); //3. Parameter Wert null ist die CursorFactory

        myContext = context;
        DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
        String RegEx = "((/data/data/(w+\\.w+/w+/w+/))w+\\.w+)"; // /data/data/wolfgang_jakobi.anglerapp/databases/Angler.sqlite3
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(RegEx);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(DB_PATH);
        String [] Groups = new String[3];
        if (m.find()) {
            Groups[0] = m.group(1); // /data/data/wolfgang_jakobi.anglerapp/databases/Angler.sqlite3
            Groups[1] = m.group(2); // /data/data/wolfgang_jakobi.anglerapp/databases/
            Groups[2] = m.group(4); // wolfgang_jakobi.anglerapp/databases/
        }

        DB_PATH_COMPLETE = Groups[0];
        DB_PATH = Groups[1];
        DB_PATH_DISPLAY = Groups[2];

        SQL_DB = super.getReadableDatabase();
    }
```

Alas the condition m.find() becomes not true so the code continues after the condition-bracket and all my Groups keep empty, I have no idea, why.

Thank you for your recomendations.

Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex is wrong.

> ```
> "((/data/data/(w+\\.w+/w+/w+/))w+\\.w+)"
> ```

It looks like you're trying to use the *word character predefined character class*, but, as written, you're just looking for `w` characters. That is, you need to use `\\w` instead of `w` in your pattern.

```
"((/data/data/(\\w+\\.\\w+/\\w+/\\w+/))\\w+\\.\\w+)"
```

Comment: Thank you, Ben. I'll try it out and report the result, soonly.

Comment: Hi Ben, did this RegExp "((/data/data/(\\w+\\.\\w+/\\w+/\\w+/))\\w+\\.\\w+)" work fine for you? In my class I had the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

I developed software with regular expressions in C++ and ABAP, alas I did not follow here in Android Studio (JAVA) the same strategy: The known pattern-groups one has to set litarally into the regular expression and later on one can replace gradually every group by  wildcards, in the present problem I used the wildcard "\w+" as Ben recomended.

Doing this I discovered, that my grouping was erronious, because the 3rd "w+" was superflouous, but I never tried out if this error had any influence.

Here my new code, where I left every step of replacement by wildcards as a comment:

```
@SuppressWarnings("JavaDoc")

public class DBUtility extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "Angler.sqlite3";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1; //minimal 1, 0 nicht zulÃ¤ssig.

    private String DB_PATH_COMPLETE;
    private String DB_PATH;
    private String DB_PATH_DISPLAY;
    private SQLiteDatabase SQL_DB;
    private Context myContext;
    private String displayText;
    private BufferedReader Rdr;
    private char[] SQLstringAr;
    private String SQLstatementFile;
    private Cursor cur;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DBUtility(Context context) {
        // Kann nicht private werden
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION); //3. Parameter Wert null ist die CursorFactory

        myContext = context;
        DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
        //String RegEx = "((/data/data/(wolfgang_jakobi\\.anglerapp/databases/))Angler\\.sqlite3)";
        //                  /data/data/ wolfgang_jakobi  .anglerapp/databases/Angler.sqlite3
        //String RegEx = "((/data/data/(\\w+\\.anglerapp/databases/))Angler\\.sqlite3)";
        //String RegEx = "((/data/data/(\\w+\\.\\w+/databases/))Angler\\.sqlite3)";
        //String RegEx = "((/data/data/(\\w+\\.\\w+/\\w+/))Angler\\.sqlite3)";
        //String RegEx = "((/data/data/(\\w+\\.\\w+/\\w+/))\\w+\\.sqlite3)";
        String RegEx =      "((/data/data/(\\w+\\.\\w+   /\\w+/))\\w+\\.\\w+)";
        // previous version "((/data/data/(  w+\\.  w+/w+/  w+/))w+\\.w+)"
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(RegEx);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(DB_PATH);
        String [] Groups = new String[3];
        if (m.find()) {
            Groups[0] = m.group(1); // /data/data/wolfgang_jakobi.anglerapp/databases/Angler.sqlite3
            Groups[1] = m.group(2); // /data/data/wolfgang_jakobi.anglerapp/databases/
            Groups[2] = m.group(3); // wolfgang_jakobi.anglerapp/databases/
        }

        DB_PATH_COMPLETE = Groups[0];
        DB_PATH = Groups[1];
        DB_PATH_DISPLAY = Groups[2];

        SQL_DB = super.getReadableDatabase();
    }
```

This code works fine.

Greetings Wolfgang

Comment: Doing this I discovered, that my grouping was erronious, because the 3rd "w+"    was superflouous, but I never tried out if this error had any influence.

Comment: It is obviously that the structure and the content of the regexp must fit any part of the matcher-string, otherwise the method m.find() will not become true.